# Where to get legal and graphic advice

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I tried doing a Google search, but nothing useful came out there, instead an iPhone popped up. I wanted to ask legal questions related to graphic designing don't know where to go though.

Particularly I wanted to model and texture an iPhone, and I don't know if the rights allow it.

Comment: To be able to give a good recommendation you might want to add your exact question. If it is just the last line you presented here I'm afraid it will be too broad everywhere.

Comment: @rene, there are a lot of tuts out there, I wonder if they all asked for permisson,and I am just presenting one topic about if it would be ok to model and texture an iphone(of course using their logo comes here) so , I wanted to make sure if me doing it would be all right., If you do think it would be too broad please suggest me a 'rephrasable' question to narrow it down.

Comment: It looks like you just started to make your specific question less broad. I'm not the problem owner, it is your job to make your question on-topic. Including what you already researched and what you concluded based on that is info that could help the question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your precise question.

You could have a look at [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), which has the tags [legal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) and [copyright](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright).

I'm not active there myself, you will have to verify for yourself that the question is on-topic there. You should check their Help Center for this.

I'm pretty certain the site will warn you that their legal advice is taken at your own risk. Depending on what it is that you need to know, you may need to consult a lawyer IRL, and expect to pay.

As a side note, as it seems to be about a specific issue, **do not** post it on Law Stack Exchange. Asking for specific legal advice is [explicitly off-topic there](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice).

Comment: But, if the question is broad enough "US laws regulating depictions of trademarked/copywritten products" it may be fine on law. Would it not?